# Delphi XE4 cannot install design package (vcl) for 64bit configuration

Tags: delphi, installation, package, vcl

I've installed XE4 on a 64bit Windows 7. All my design packages can be compiled/installed in 32bit configration. If I switch configuration to 64bit, the "Install" and "Uninstall" commands will disappear from context menu.

It is weird, can someone know the reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Delphi IDE is a 32 bit app and so there are no 64 bit design time packages. Simply put, there is nothing into which a 64 bit design time package can be installed.

Of course, for run time packages, you can compile and use both 32 and 64 bit versions.

Comment: Do you mean, Delphi cannot build a native 64bit Windows Vcl application?

Comment: No I do not mean that. I mean the Delphi IDE is a 32 bit app and so needs 32 bit design time packages. It is capable of building apps for 32 and 64 bit Windows, 32 bit Mac, and ARM v7 iOS and Android. Remember that design time packages exist solely to be hosted by the IDE.

Comment: To add to what David said, the IDE is smart enough to use 64bit runtime packages when compiling a 64bit project, even though it has to use 32bit designtime packages. The compiler stores extra info in a 32bit designtime package if there is an associated 64bit runtime package so the IDE knows that it is safe to use the 32bit designtime package in a 64bit project.